# Rewriting this Riemann sum as a definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, summation

Can someone help me rewrite this Riemann sum as a definite integral?

> $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(-7+\frac{14i}{n} \right)^9\sin\left(4+ \left(-7+\frac{14i}{n} \right)^8 \right)$

$\Delta x=\frac{1}{n}$ so this means $b-a=1$. If I rewrite the $\frac{14i}{n}$ as $14\frac{i}{n}$, then this means I could say that $a=0$ and $b=1$ so this means my definite integral is:

$$\int_{0}^{1}(-7+14x)^9\sin(4+(-7+14x)^8)dx$$ but I am not sure if this is correct or not.

If this IS correct, how would I do this integral with no integration technique other than u-substitution or manipulation? I can't seem to do it otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming partition points are of the form $x_i=a+i \frac{b-a}{n}$, it looks like $a=-7$ and $b-a=14$ so $b=7$. The $1/n$ that's pulled out of the sum is misleading. Rewrite it as $1/n=\frac{1}{14}\cdot \frac{14}{n}$. This leads to the integral
$$
\frac{1}{14}\int_{-7}^7 x^9 \sin(4+x^8)
$$
Hint: To evaluate the integral, take note of the bounds and types of functions.

Comment: Yes I see it. It's an odd function so the bounds are equal but opposite. So the integral is 0. Thank you!